# Replace text of element on hover jQuery JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I hover over whole DIV kontakt-block I need to have text in span TEXT-DISPLAY changed.
I will do it by myself when there's only one kontakt-block. But when it goes to classes i can not. In each span i need to have different text to appear on hover.

```
<div class="kontakt-block color1" onmouseover="changeText('email@gmail.com')" onmouseout="defaultText('Email')">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Email</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color2">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Phone</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color3">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Facebook</span>
     </div>
</div>

<script>
                    function changeText(text) {
                        var display = document.getElementsById('text-display');
                        display.innerHTML = "";
                        display.innerHTML = text;
                    }
                    function defaultText(textd) {
                        var display = document.getElementsById('text-display');
                        display.innerHTML = "";
                        display.innerHTML = textd;
                    }
</script>
```

Here's what i did. It works but while there's only one span to change.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! have you tried any code yet, please show us what you have tried so far even if you have failed, show us some effort ;)

Comment: The first thing to become familiar with are contextual lookups, and then how to change the text of an element.  After that it's just a question of determining what text you should swap in/out.

Comment: You can show us how you did with only one kontakt-block first

Comment: Do you want to continue using the inline bindings or do you care?  Because if so, this becomes a javascript problem, rather than a jQuery related problem.

Comment: I don't have to use js. I don't mind if you change it all. I started learing JS this year in school. And jquery, i don't know at all. And this code in topic doesn't work.

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex  Its not recommended to mix HTML content with JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic uses the data fields to know what values to set.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.kontakt-block').forEach(function(block){
  block.addEventListener('mouseenter', changeText);
  block.addEventListener('mouseleave', defaultText);
});

function changeText (e) {
  var $span = $(e.target).find('.text-display')
    .fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $span.text(e.target.dataset.hoverValue).fadeIn();
    });
}

function defaultText (e) {
  var $span = $(e.target).find('.text-display')
    .fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $span.text(e.target.dataset.defaultValue).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kontakt-block color1" data-default-value="Email" data-hover-value="email@gmail.com">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Email</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color2" data-default-value="Phone" data-hover-value="123-456-7890">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Phone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color3" data-default-value="Facebook" data-hover-value="fbHandle">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Facebook</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you all for help. You are really helpfull. I've already done this thanks to other someguy. One more thing, do you now any way to make text appear more smootly. Like transition-duration in css?

Comment: You mean like a fade in? @LazyArtistSQuex

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex  I gave them a fade in, fade out effect

Comment: Exactly. So it look more smooth

Comment: Sorry man, but it seems like your code doesn't work on me:c But @Myles works and there's no fadeIn

Comment: @LazyArtistSQuex  it doesn't work when you run the snipplet?  It works for me here on site.

Comment: @Taplar Works for me too

Comment: sorry give me a seccond

Comment: If you want to change duration you have to write this? - $span.text(e.target.dataset.defaultValue).fadeIn(0.75s);

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is use pure css and html, just one option for you

```css
.text-display2 {
  display:none;
}

.kontakt-block:hover .text-display {
  display:none;
}

.kontakt-block:hover .text-display2 {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="kontakt-block color1">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Email</span>
          <span class="text-display2">Email2</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color2">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Phone</span>
       <span class="text-display2">Phone2</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color3">
     <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
          <span class="text-display">Facebook</span>
       <span class="text-display2">Facebook2</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried working with css, but i failed a couple of times. it was changing but my site and divs fall off. Btw thanks!

Comment: This is a good method too, and has more potential for a fade in transition, I think

Comment: Yes. Now i have problem with transition-duration with JavaScript. But its changing yay!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is kind of what you're trying to do.

```js
function changeMyText(obj, text) {
  var workingObj = obj.children;
  var oneDeeper = workingObj[0].children;
  oneDeeper[0].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div class="kontakt-block color1" onmouseover="changeMyText(this, 'Changed text 1')" onmouseout="changeMyText(this, 'Email')">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Email</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color2" onmouseover="changeMyText(this, 'Changed text 2')" onmouseout="changeMyText(this, 'Phone')">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Phone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color3" onmouseover="changeMyText(this, 'Changed text 3')" onmouseout="changeMyText(this, 'Facebook')">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Facebook</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you Sir and all of you? One more thing, do you now any way to make text appear more smootly. Like transition-duration in css?

Comment: Okay, nevermind. Someone did this in javascript below. But thanks, your code worked for me at first!

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript and CSS for transition:

```js
function changeText() {
  var span = this.querySelector('.text-display');
  setText(span, this.dataset.sample);
}

function defaultText() {
  var span = this.querySelector('.text-display');
  setText(span, this.dataset.default);
}

function setText(span, text) {
  span.classList.add('hide');
  setTimeout(function() {
     span.innerHTML = text;
     span.classList.remove('hide');
  }, 310, span, text);
}

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('kontakt-block');
for (var div of [...divs]) {
  div.addEventListener("mouseover", changeText, false);
  div.addEventListener("mouseout", defaultText, false);
}
```

```css
.text-display.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.text-display {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="kontakt-block color1" data-default="Email" data-sample="email@gmail.com">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Email</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color2" data-default="Phone" data-sample="123-456-7890">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Phone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="kontakt-block color3" data-default="Facebook" data-sample="Login with FB">
  <div class="kontakt-block-zawartosc">
    <span class="text-display">Facebook</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This uses the same mouseover text for all of them, but the OP seems to need different text for each one.

Comment: Thanks you all for help. You are really helpfull. I've already done this thanks to other someguy. One more thing, do you now any way to make text appear more smootly. Like transition-duration in css?

Comment: Added transition duration in CSS